# Создание фоновой задачи с#

Tags: c#

Читала несколько гайдов, как создать и зарегистрировать фоновую задачу.
Есть файл, который содержится в отдельном проекте. Содержание файла:

```
namespace background
{
    public sealed class MyBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {

        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            await DoWork(taskInstance);

            throw new NotImplementedException();
            _deferral.Complete();
        }

        private async Task DoWork(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {

           //задача, которая должна выполнятся в фоновом...
        }
    }
}
```

И часть кода, которая записана в определенный файл в основном проекте:

```
var taskRegistered = false;
              var exampleTaskName = "MyBackgroundTask";

              foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
              {
                  if (task.Value.Name == exampleTaskName)
                  {
                      taskRegistered = true;
                      break;
                  }

              }
              var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

              builder.Name = exampleTaskName;
              builder.TaskEntryPoint = "backgroung.MyBackgroundTask";

              appTrigger = new ApplicationTrigger();

              builder.SetTrigger(appTrigger);


              appTrigger.RequestAsync();
```

Насколько я поняла, `appTrigger.RequestAsync();` должно запускать фоновую задачу в том месте, где прописано. Но, как раз на эту строку, начинает ругаться данным образом и не дает программе работать дальше, после этой строки:

> Warning   CS4014  Because this call is not awaited, execution of the
>   current method continues before the call is completed. Consider
>   applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить возникшую проблему?

Comment: *"Но, как раз на эту строку, начинает ругаться данным образом **и не дает программе работать дальше**"* - не верю!

Comment: По вопросу же - что такое `IBackgroundTaskInstance`? Что такое `BackgroundTaskDeferral`? Что такое `ApplicationTrigger`? Зачем все так сложно сделано? Какая вообще задача решается? Что вы понимаете под словами "фоновая задача"?

Comment: Серьезно это самый упоротый вариант написать фоновую задачу из всех что я видел. Нет чтобы просто Thread или Task тот же использовать в пару строк.

Answer (score 1):

Убери `async` у метода `Run` он вообще не должен быть асинхронным поидее.
То есть нужно заменить:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
```

на

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
```

В целом код был верен, другое дело, что гайд с которого ты брала `BackgroundTask` расчитан на использование по триггерам, а при непосредственном запуске `async` не нужен.
Но в целом все же предпочтительнее использовать `Task` или `Thread` для таких задач, т.к. основное применение `BackgroundTask` это фоновая работа по **триггеру**, т.е. в случае ограниченного круга специфичных действий. В 90% случаев это в общем-то не нужно, учитывая, что исходя из документации по [SystemTriggerType](http://SystemTriggerType) там возможных действий кот наплакал.